# Firefox add-on SDK / places/bookmarks API: How to get *all* bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, sdk, firefox-addon-sdk, bookmarks

I am trying to access bookmarks using the [places/bookmarks API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks) from the Add-on SDK for Firefox. I am able to query the bookmarks, searching for some given keywords etc. but if I just try

```
search(
  { query: "" }
).on("end", function (results) {
  // results matching any bookmark that has "firefox"
  // in its URL, title or tag, sorted by title
  console.error(results);
}
```

I do not get any output. Is this expected? How would I do a catch-all query?

(As correctly hinted at in the comment, for small numbers of search results, the above code does return all bookmarks.)

Comment: I encounter the same problem. It looks like `search()` has a problem with large number of bookmarks.
The limit seems to be somewhere around 100, as
  `search({}, {count: 100})` works
but 
  `search({}, {count: 150})` doesn't.
I'm trying to figure out a workaround.

Comment: @MichaelKonečný, have you made any progress with this?

Comment: Not yet, sorry, I've been busy with other things. I've looked around a little bit and thought it would be probably possible to look into the SDK's source code https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/places/bookmarks.js, look at what the search() method actually does and develop my own method to get the bookmarks.
Haven't yet had the time to try anything, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct:

```
search(
    { query: "" }
    ).on("end", function (bookmarks) {
        // do something
}
```

This is exactly the way it should work. I am using the same code and have tested that the search does retrieve all my around 1500 bookmarks.

My assumption is that you made an error while testing. For example, when running "cfx run" using the Firefox SDK, the test browser does not contain your bookmarks, you would have to create or import bookmarks first.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: That's the same version I am using. I have rerun my code (with the newer Firefox 42.0) and now it works as expected.